# my javascript sounds wont play in windows XP?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio, jplayer

```
new Audio('sounds/mysound.mp3').play();
```

Im using the above javascript to play sounds on a web project, everything works fine at home on my laptop which is running Windows 7 , tested in both Firefox, and Google Chrome.

The problem i have is that on Windows XP, the sounds wont play at all? I do understand that browser support for the above is a bit sketchy at the moment, as mp3 is not fully supported apparently, in firefox for example.. so im a bit confused?? why does it play on my windows 7 machine, but not on windows xp machines, even in the same browser?

I may well have to look at doing the sounds with a plugin or something, can jPlayer play sounds with no visbable player icons etc.. as all the demos show some form of player on screen?

Any help appreciated.

Thanks Paul

EDIT***
I think if OGG files will work, i`ll have to have both sound file formats in my sounds folder, and then use a javascript variable to add the .ext required depending on what broswer is being used.

```
check which browser
extVariable = either '.mp3' or '.ogg' accordingly
new Audio('sounds/mysound'+extVariable).play();
```

That way i dont need if else statments everytime i wish to call a sound :) just set the .ext variable up at the top of page.

i made the following audio test over at http://codepen.io/PaulBrUK1972/full/pGdza
and just as i thought using windows XP, the ogg file will play in firefox, but the mp3 wont. It would be interesting to know if the mp3 plays on other peoples windows 7 machines, like it does on mine, even though it shouldnt??

Comment: Is it just Firefox or does it also fail on Chrome/IE on Windows XP?

Comment: To be truely honest, its been a while since i tested it on Windows XP, which was on 3 or 4 machines at work, but if i remember correctly im fairly sure it didnt work in chrome and firefox

Comment: I do find it all a bit wierd that Firefox is not compatible with .mp3, yet it plays mp3 sounds perfectly on my windows 7 machine in firefox ??the mind boggles??

Comment: @Paul501 what is the response on the machine in console: `document.createElement("audio").canPlayType("audio/mp3")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firefox relies on codex available on the machine to play mp3 to get around licensing issues, so that could cause issues.

If you are looking for a sound library to abstract away the issues of supporting audio on browsers with variable support, I'd recommend [SoundJS](http://www.createjs.com/#!/SoundJS), which I help develop.  It uses the latest audio standards when available, and has a flash fallback for older browsers and systems.  using SoundJS, you can write a single codebase that is broadly supported, including on mobile devices.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi, yes i since found out firefox uses the operating system on windows 7+ to allow support for mp3 plaback which explains the issue. i`ll check out SoundJs when i get chance, but i think i do believe ive sorted the issue out as explained above by checking what file type is supported in the browser and then using a javascript variable to set the file extension to either .ogg or .mp3 on the play() function accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

```
Internet Explorer 9+   can play:  MP3
Firefox 3.6+           can play:  WAV and OGG
Chrome 3+              can play:  MP3 and OGG
Safari  4+             can play:  MP3 and WAV
Opera 9.5+             can play:  WAV and OGG
```

The above is the list of music file types that can be played in the given browser, that is something i took from the book Pro HTML5 Games - Aditya Ravi Shankar. It's a good book i am still working through it though.
If the browser is not causing an issue you should check the following:
Check you have speakers/headset/earphones plugged in.
Check that the volume is not too low.
Check that other audio is working on your PC, play a track on YouTube, or some media player.
Check the sound/volume settings and adjust the settings, you may be sending audio out the incorrect channels.
Check that you have an up to date sound driver.
If that doesn't work check that your sound card is not broken.

Comment: I obviously checked the sound was working on the windows XP machines, before conducting the tests..

Comment: I am not trying to be condescending Paul, i am trying to write down all the possibilities so you have a list of things you can mark off the list. Sometimes its better to not make an assumption as to what the author has done thus far.

Comment: I know you wasnt, thats why i didnt mark you down, sorry if i came across that way, its just frustrating, cant get my head round it.

Comment: i also noticed one thing, you should try to use this var bulletAudioReady = false;
var bulletAudio = new Audio(); bulletAudio.onload = function(){
bulletAudioReady = true;
};
bulletAudio.src = "audio/BulletShot(1).mp3"; bulletAudio.play();
That way, the sound will only be played when everything is loaded

Comment: I dont really have any issues like that tommy, as everything is written in jquery & javascript and uses the document.ready function, there are hundreds of sounds that can be played depending on what is happening at the time.

Comment: i recommend you then try to get that MP3 converted into OGG and WAV and try to use each. You could use an if statement to check that if 1 version cannot be played then the other music files would be instead (if(hit.canPlayType === true){
     hit.play();
     }
     else{
     bulletAudio.play();
     }) if you still have issues then consider adjusting the sound card. Also make sure that the music file itself is greater than 0b. If after all that, no solution is found try doing a driver re-installation

Comment: Thats Tommy, I`ll have to do some tests with OGG as you suggest, and then use the if statement to pick between mp3 and OGG, hopefully that will address the issue, i`ll keep you posted. luckily there is only a handfull or 2 of the sound triggers themselves, although the sound it plays is dynamic, there only small mp3 sounds so that again could be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

What most html5 sound libraries, such as sm2, do to get around the fact that [some browsers support only certain audio types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Supported_media_formats) is call `document.createElement("audio").canPlayType(type)` before creating the `audio` element for the sound.

So I suggest you make a helper function in creating your audio sounds that could look something as what follows (sorry if theres errors untested):

```
var audioTypes = {
   "ogg": "audio/ogg",
   "mp3": "audio/mp3"//etc
}

//src is an array of sources for a type
var createAudio = function(src, options) {
    var audio = document.createElement("audio");
    for (var i = 0; i < src.length; i++) {
        var type = src[i].slice(src[i].lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
        if(audio.canPlayType(audioTypes[type]) {
            audio.type = audioTypes[type];
            audio.src = src[i];
            return audio;
        }
    }
    throw "Unsupported audio";
}
```

Now just call

```
var mySound = createAudio(["sounds/mySound.ogg", "sounds/mySound.mp3"]);
```